# Intel RealSense - Development Tool

Tags: windows, intellisense, intel, augmented-reality, realsense

I going to develop one application by using intel realsense sdk. I want to know which development tool ( Unity3d, .Not ) is best for that ? am good in C#.

Please suggest me ?

Comment: @RohitGupta this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat, ok - I have read that and you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you definitely can try unity!
i've done some project in the past using intel realsense sdk+unity and they worked flawlessly.

the documentation is also great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C# SDK: https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-realsense-sdk

Or.. if you want something more simple, easy to use (and less powerful), try: SharpSenses: https://github.com/SharpSenses/SharpSenses

Disclaimer: I'm the author of SharpSenses :)